# Prove domain and whether the function - f(x) = 1/(1 + |x|) is one to one.

Tags: functions

I am a first year Computer Science student studying Calculus and Linear Algebra this semester.

I have got two questions:

1. how to find domain regarding finding the domain of the following function.
2. Is this function one to one?

***Question - 1 - Domain - My understanding***

```
f(x) = 1/(1+ |x|)
```

- 1 + |x|, denominator can never be 0.
- |x| is an absolute value, therefore it can be any number.
- Therefore the domain is (-α, α).

```
However, the solution is as follows and I do not understand this solution.
1 + |x| >= 1 

1/(1 + |x|) <= 1

0 < 1/(1 + |x|) <= 1 for all x E (-α, α)
```

***Question - 2 - One to One function or Not***

```
y = 1/(1 + |x|)

1 + |x| = 1/y

|x| = 1/y -1
x = +- (1/y -1)

From here, I can see that y must be greater than 0 since the denominator cannot be 0.
```

I get stuck here. I had to use wolframalpha site to plot the graph. Without using this website, how should I procced to test for one-to-one function?
[Graph Plot to check one-to-one function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd03g.jpg)
My understanding is that since there are two x values (+-) for each corresponding y, it is not one to one. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks very much.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+1%2F+%281+%2B+%7Cx%7C%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$ as you have observed. The function is not one-to-one because $f(-1)=f(1)$.

Comment: Oh I see.  f(-1) = 1/(1+|-1|) = 1/2,  f(1) = 1/(1+|1|) = 1/2. Therefore it is not one to one. How do you know the shape of the graph without using the wolfram site (instead of substituting each numbers)? Thanks!

Comment: @Su ス, that comes under graphical transformations. https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Mathematics/OCR/C3/Special_Functions_and_Transformations

Comment: if you know the graph of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ (which is a shifted hyperbola), $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$  will be symmetric along y axis , as f(x)=f(-x)

Comment: @user675453 Thanks! I do know that 1/(1+x) graph. My apology :).

Comment: @user675453 Thanks@